# Is a blank really a directory when dealing with mod-rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I spent about 20 minutes wrapping my head around this, and finally came to a solution but did not know why it worked. The important lines (as it relates to this question) in the apache configuration file looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^$ /abc [L]
```

When I tried accessing http://example.com, the last rewriterule is skipped but what I do not understand is **how is nothing a directory**?

Based on the last three items from the way I see it, I'm checking to see if I'm requesting a file or a folder, and if not, then redirect nothing (aka the default page) to `/abc.`

It turns out here that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` returns false because when I remove it and try again using the configuration shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^$ /abc [L]
```

the redirection then works.

Is there a reason as to why "nothing" counts as a directory?
I don't want to fall into any more illogical traps like this as I update my website.

Comment: I read this and am not sure I understand *why "nothing" counts as a directory* except if example.com results in example.com/ which is totally normal and required. The URL is example.com and the URI is the path and file. If the URI is blank, the assumption is /. The browser adds the / URI if no URI exists. However, if example.com/abc is used, abc cannot be known to the browser and so it is passed where the server searches for the first match (directory) and a / is added. Is this what you are looking for??

Comment: ok it makes sense. so nothing equals a `/`

Comment: Yeppers! I gotta type 6 more characters but by now I have overshot that by quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase you are not checking that *nothing* is a directory, you are checking whether `REQUEST_FILENAME` is a directory (or not in this case).

Whilst the URL-path, that matches against the `RewriteRule` pattern, is *nothing* (after the directory-prefix is removed), the `REQUEST_FILENAME` (which contains the absolute filesystem path that the request maps to, ie. *not a URL*) will contain something like `/home/username/public_html/` (depending on your config). This is a directory on the local filesystem, so the above `RewriteCond` evaluates to *false*.